# JBoss EAP 6.2 and Log4j2 stops writing logs after some time

Tags: jboss, log4j2, jboss-eap-6

I am using Log4j2 (`RollingFile` with routes) in my web application to log application specific logs in a few separate log files. The `log4j2.xml` file is bundled with in the WAR file.

Log files are generated and logs are generating fine to start with. After some time, it stops writing logs to the existing file and fails creating new folders/files too.

On restart everything resumes working and that is for some time only.
Tried monitoring, couldn't figure out any specific pattern or steps to simulate it.

```
<Configuration status="error" name="logger">
  <Properties>
  <Property name="logpath">path_to_log_file</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
  <Routing name="RoutingUserLogFile">
     <Routes pattern="$${ctx:user}/">
        <Route>
           <RollingFile name="UserLogFile" fileName="${logpath}/${ctx:user}/MyLogFile.log" filePattern="${logpath}/${ctx:user}/%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-MyLogFile-%i.log.gz">
              <PatternLayout>
                 <Pattern>%d %p %-40C{1.} %m%n</Pattern>
              </PatternLayout>
              <Policies>
                 <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
                 <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="4 MB" />
              </Policies>
           </RollingFile>
        </Route>
     </Routes>
  </Routing>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
   <Root>
      <level value="debug" />
      <AppenderRef ref="RoutingUserLogFile" level="debug" />
   </Root>
 </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: I would not suggest to use your own logger bundled with your application. Use the JBoss EAP logging instead. You can use Log4J 1 as well. The configuration of the logger and the application log file can be done in the standalone.xml

Comment: I will not be able to use JBoss logging or Log4j2 directly with JBoss as i have few routing conditions, that is a folder will generated for every user and under which log file is. So setting routing pattern value might not be possible with the approach you suggested. Above is my sample log4j2.xml configuration.

Comment: I see. Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: There are no errors or exception raised in JBoss logs. :(